# howler.js sprite sound resume after pause

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, howler.js

I am trying to setup an audio sprite with `Howler.js`. The basic sprite functionality works fine but if I pause a sprite, how can I resume playback on it? Calling `play()` doesn't work for me.

```
sound = new Howl({
  urls: ['http://<your audio asset>'],
  sprite: {
    frame1: [260, 4400],
    frame2: [4700, 2400],
    frame3: [7100, 2200],
    frame4: [9300, 2100],
    frame5: [11400,5100],
    frame6: [16500, 3000]
  }
});
----------------HTML-------------------
<button onclick="sound.play('frame6')">
Play Frame 6
</button>
<button onclick="sound.pause()">
Pause
</button>
<button onclick="sound.play()">
Play
</button>
```

My sequence of steps

1. Play Frame 6
2. Pause
3. Play (expected: resume playing frame6. actual: no sound at all)

Comment: This is one of the issues that is being solved in 2.0. I would recommend switching to the 2.0 branch (currently beta, but very stable), which fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Just set 'frame6' at pause() and play() and it works...

```
----------------HTML-------------------
<button onclick="sound.play('frame6')">
Play Frame 6
</button>
<button onclick="sound.pause('frame6')">
Pause
</button>
<button onclick="sound.play('frame6')">
Play
</button>
```